# SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined using python 3.9

Tags: python, django, numpy

I am using python 3.9 in a virtual environment.  The only solution I can find just says to use python 3.7 or higher and try using a virtual environment to ensure it is.  I am doing both and as you can see from the backtrace, it is indeed using 3.9.

edit:  we just found in this stack trace, two lines where it is some reason going outside our virtual environment and hitting the system python3.6 for some reason.  We have no clue as to why this is happening.

```
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/token-auth/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 288, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 545, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/mktplace/market/market/market/urls.py", line 47, in <module>
    path(prepath, include('reporting.urls'), name='payg_v1_reporting')
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/mktplace/market/market/reporting/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import invoices_by_month, monthly_utilized, total_funds_utilized_by_month, total_funds_utilized_gauge, total_funds_utilized, monthly_average_return, invoice_status_by_month, invoice_current_statuses
  File "/workspace/mktplace/market/market/reporting/views.py", line 448, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.version import version as __version__
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/version.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations
                                     ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

second edit:  we removed all pip installed packages in our virtual environment and reinstalled.  We now get a different stack trace, but it seems to lead back to importlib package going outside our virtual environment and using the system's python 3.6 for some reason.

```
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/token-auth/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 288, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 545, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/mktplace/market/market/market/urls.py", line 47, in <module>
    path(prepath, include('reporting.urls'), name='payg_v1_reporting')
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/mktplace/market/market/reporting/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import invoices_by_month, monthly_utilized, total_funds_utilized_by_month, total_funds_utilized_gauge, total_funds_utilized, monthly_average_return, invoice_status_by_month, invoice_current_statuses
  File "/workspace/mktplace/market/market/reporting/views.py", line 448, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from ._globals import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'ModuleDeprecationWarning'
```

The other thing we noticed, our developer does a pip install on our requirements.txt and he gets a smaller set of packages installed than I do and he doesn't get this importlib package like I do.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. It is not very clear what you are asking. Provide the setup in terms of what you are trying to do, and pieces of code you think may cause this.

Comment: I am not sure what else to elaborate on.  I am getting the syntax error I posted and I am trying to find the cause so I can resolve it.  The stack trace provides the code that is causing it.  I just don't know why.  As i already stated in my question, all other posts with this error indicate an issue with using python version prior to 3.7 which resolved their issue, but that is not my case here as the stack trace clearly shows v3.9 being used.

Comment: Did you see you have references to python3.6? : `/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py`. Perhaps python path problems?

Comment: Yep, we just found it actually, hidden in between all the paths to our python3.9.  100% confused as to why.  We are doing this all in a virtual environment using python3.9.  Thanks for your help.  I guess this is a 3.6 python issue, but now we have to figure out how/why its switching to 3.6 in two places here.

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to recreate the venv. Most likely some streams got crossed at some point with some wonky installation or upgrade.

Comment: looks like an issue with matplotlib/numpy packages?  I uninstalled those and removed one line reference to those packages and everything worked again.